# Download multiple files at a time from using HTTP Rest API Calls

Tags: development, rest, api

I am able to download a file from SharePoint using the API `GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl`.

However I'm looking to download selected files at once from SharePoint. Is there any possibility to do this?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there are no REST methods for retrieving multiple files at a time.

But you can [make requests](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest?redirectedfrom=MSDN#working-with-files-by-using-rest) in parallel if you know the files' URLs.

And wait until all the requests are processed with [Promise.all(requestsArray)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).